# Vim errorformat and spectral lint

Tags: vim, swagger, openapi, spectral

I am attempting to define an error format for the Spectral OpenAPI linter (https://github.com/stoplightio/spectral). The code I have is below, but what I'm seeing is that after I run `:make` the quickfix window populates with lines from Spectral, but I can't navigate to error spots using it. There are no errors in Vim, the quick fix window just doesn't do much.

The messages from Spectral look like this:

```
/path/to/sample.yaml:25:9 error oas3-schema "Property `think` is not expected to be here."
```

My current Vimscript looks like this:

```
function! OpenAPIDetect()
    if getline(1) =~ 'openapi:'
        let &l:makeprg='spectral lint "' .  expand('%') . '" -f text'
        setlocal errorformat=%f:%l:%c\ (information\\|warning\\|error)\ (\\w\\|-)\+\ %m
        setlocal errorformat+=%-GOpenAPI\ 3.x\ detected
    endif
endfunction

augroup filetypedetect
    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.{yml,yaml} call OpenAPIDetect()
augroup END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should be enough:

```
setlocal errorformat=%f:%l:%c\ %t%.%\\{-}\ %m
```

- `%f:%l:%c` matches the colon-separated filename, line, and column,
- `%t` matches a single character, used to infer the type of the error (`error` if `e`, `warning` if `w`, `info` if `i`, `hint` is not supported),
- `%.%\\{-}` skips over the rest of the "type" word,
- `%m` matches the rest of the message.

Also, the right place for `:help 'errorformat'` and `:help 'makeprg'` would be a `:help :compiler` file:

```
" in a minimal compiler/spectral.vim
if exists("current_compiler")
    finish
endif
let current_compiler = "spectral"
CompilerSet makeprg=spectral\ lint\ %\ -f\ text
CompilerSet errorformat=%f:%l:%c\ %t%.%\\{-}\ %m
```

and the right place for that OpenAPI detection logic would be a `:help ftplugin`:

```
" in a minimal after/ftplugin/yaml.vim
if getline(1) =~ 'openapi:'
    compiler spectral
endif
```

[image: example]

Comment: This is incredibly useful, thanks! Taking a cue from your message, I went ahead and created the compiler definition and pushed a copy up to Github, in case it is useful to anyone else: https://github.com/michaeljmcd/spectral.vim